# RxJava: Why can't I test retryWhen using TestScheduler?

Tags: rx-java, netflix-feign, spring-cloud-feign

I've the following test that uses WireMock to stub a HTTP service that fails twice, and then succeeds. I'm using `retryWhen` with exponential backoff, so the first retry attempt (2nd call) will be 2 seconds after the first, the 2nd retry (3rd and successful call) will happen 4 seconds after the 2nd call. I try to advance the clock using `TestScheduler.advanceTimeBy` but the test fails when verifying `onNext` events (error: `Expected size:<1> but was:<0>`). If I replace `TestScheduler` with `Schedulers.computation()`, everything works.
What am I doing wrong?

```
@Test
public void testRetry() throws IOException {
    server.stubFor(get(urlPathEqualTo(RANDOM_JOKE_URI))
            .inScenario("Feign retry")
            .whenScenarioStateIs(STARTED)
            .willReturn(badRequest())
            .willSetStateTo("1"));

    server.stubFor(get(urlPathEqualTo(RANDOM_JOKE_URI))
            .inScenario("Feign retry")
            .whenScenarioStateIs("1")
            .willReturn(badRequest())
            .willSetStateTo("2"));

    server.stubFor(get(urlPathEqualTo(RANDOM_JOKE_URI))
            .inScenario("Feign retry")
            .whenScenarioStateIs("2")
            .willReturn(ok()
                    .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .withBody(copyToByteArray(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/joke.json")))));

    TestSubscriber<JokeServiceResponse> subscriber = new TestSubscriber<>();
    TestScheduler scheduler = new TestScheduler();
    // GOTCHA ALERT: must use defer for the Observable to be reevaluated
    Observable.defer(() -> client.tellAJoke()
            .toObservable())
            .retryWhen(errors -> onErrorTryAgain(errors, scheduler))
            .subscribe(subscriber);

    scheduler.advanceTimeBy(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    subscriber.assertNoValues();
    scheduler.advanceTimeBy(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    subscriber.assertNoValues();
    subscriber.awaitTerminalEvent(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    subscriber.assertNoErrors();
    assertThat(subscriber.getOnNextEvents())
            .hasSize(1)
            .is(new Condition<JokeServiceResponse>() {
                @Override
                public boolean matches(JokeServiceResponse response) {
                    assertResponse(response);
                    return true;
                }
            }, atIndex(0));
}

private Observable<?> onErrorTryAgain(Observable<? extends Throwable> errors, Scheduler scheduler) {
    return errors
            .zipWith(Observable.range(1, 5), (t, i) -> new SimpleImmutableEntry<Integer, Throwable>(i, t))
            .flatMap(e -> {
                // Can inspect Throwable here and decide whether to retry or return Observable.error
                return Observable.timer((long) Math.pow(2, e.getKey()),
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS, scheduler);
            });
}
```

Comment: I suggest using `doOnNext()` after `errors` and after the inner `timer` to see those events are actually happening.

Comment: @akarnokd I see the first stacktrace, then it fails. Your [RetreyWhenTest](https://github.com/davidmoten/rxjava-extras/blob/master/src/test/java/com/github/davidmoten/rx/RetryWhenTest.java) is similar, perhaps you can add a test with `defer` and variable delay. I suspect that the variable delay (I can't predict how long WireMock is going to take to respond) is what's causing this issue.

Comment: If there is a real time component along with the TestScheduler then yes, moving the virtual time ahead may have no effect. So either you make that source synchronous or introduce sleeps before advancing the scheduler.